# Correlate calls across async boundaries?

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, async-await

I need to correlate calls made across async methods for a monitoring tool (mostly timing information on a per high level request).

For example - for a web server request, I'd like to know how much time was spent in MethodA, MethodC and MethodH each, where some of these may by in a call hierarchy between themselves.

If there were no async methods involved (and assuming a single threaded app), a `ThreadLocal<T>` with a request life time would basically work, but given that an async call may get despatched by any thread this is not an option.

On the full framework I could have used `HttpContext`, but this isn't available in .NET core.

Outside of passing a context parameter down to each monitored method (whether manually or via AOP of some sort), what are the options?

Comment: `HttpContext` is still there, but it's no longer a global. It can still be accessed from any controller, or bu injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-2.2) is the most appropriate solution. AsyncLocal is an abstraction over the ExecutionContext that was added for this sort of scenario. Updates to it effect child async calls across async boundaries and any parts of the parent resumed to from this method, but not any async calls that where started before the update and are still ongoing.

This is used in [OpenTracing](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-csharp/blob/master/src/OpenTracing/Util/AsyncLocalScopeManager.cs) for this exact use case. You set the AsyncLocal on entering a Request Handler, and then clear it on exit:

```
class Example
{
    static AsyncLocal<string> requestId = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    static async Task Handler()
    {
        requestId.Value = GetRequestId();
        await DoWork();
        requestId.Value = null;
     }
}
```